# Frequently Accessed Objects/Classes

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

Within my Swift application, there are two classes that I interact with in almost 75% of the app. One is a set of settings called UserSettings, and the other is called Job. These both are stored in sqllite.

Most of the time it's just reading values already set, and on one areas it also writes. It seems strange to have to keep reinstantiating my settings and job services to communicate with my database to get back to me the same object i'm accessing across the board.

In a case like this, the options to me see to be either

1. constantly reading/writing to the database, or
2. do some sort of singleton accessed throughout the entire app.

I'm not sure how much Swift changes anything in terms of arriving at an answer to this question, but I wanted to seek the help of Stack Overflow. How do I set an object that I can access throughout the entire app? Or is it not ideal and instead I need to get it from my db every time?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read how core data works, I know you are managing your own store, but the architecture works fine. As a summary you can create a "context object"(this could be your singleton) who interacts with your store (sqlite) creating managed objects, you will work with this objects who are associated with the "context object", and when ever you need to save the changes, you ask the "context object" to write all the managed objects in the store.

Your managed objects need to be only a copy of the "context object" objects, so when you ask to "save" data to the "context object" you only copy back this managed objects. This will help with save multithread coding. (Your context object should work on a serialized queue).

Again this is just a summary, you should read how core data works to get a better picture.

Edit:

Read this blog: http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-overview.html
The difference is that you only need one store and one context object.

Comment: Could I also use NSUserDefaults? I'm mostly just re-reading values frequently.

Comment: NSUserDefaults it's only a manager of a plist file. If your data is already stored on a sqlite db, why you what to store it again? This will be really slow because you will be reading a file to write in other one.